# JavaScript comparison

Tags: javascript

Why my comparison in if doesn't work? The answer should be 8 but it returns 0.

```
   function findMissing(missingArray){
     var getArray = missingArray.sort();
     var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
       for(var i=0 ; i< myArray.length ; i++){
         for(var j=0 ; j< getArray.length ; j++){
            if(myArray[i] != getArray[j]){
                  return i;
          }
      }
   }
}
findMissing([0,3,4,5,7,2,9,1,6]);
```

Comment: Why do you think the answer should be 8?  It clearly returns 0 when i===0 and j===1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it with 1 loop and array search to find the missing element. Looping over both arrays index gets changed every time and that comparison is not valid.

**No Frills**

```
 function findMissing(missingArray){
     var getArray = missingArray.sort();
     var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
       for(var i=0 ; i< myArray.length ; i++){
         if(getArray.indexOf(myArray[i])==-1)
            return i;
      }

  }
alert(findMissing([0,3,4,5,7,2,9,1,6]));     //8
```

**Edit, Frills Version**
In fact you can create an array of all the missing elements, not just one. That be nice

```
 function findMissing(missingArray){
     var getArray = missingArray.sort();
     var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
     var returnArray=[];
       for(var i=0 ; i< myArray.length ; i++){
         if(getArray.indexOf(myArray[i])==-1)
             returnArray.push(myArray[i]);
      }
  return returnArray;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D859d/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
  function findMissing(missingArray){
     var getArray = missingArray.sort();

     var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 

       for(var i=0 ; i< myArray.length ; i++){

            if(myArray[i] != getArray[i]){
                  return i;          
      }
   }
}
alert(findMissing([0,3,4,5,7,2,9,1,6]));
```

this should work now.

Comment: Nope Array size is not the same. Count those numbers

Comment: Although that comment is removed from the answer but still this wont answer the question. What if one array has length 10 and other has 5? you are using same index for both arrays which wont work if counts are not same.

Answer (score 0):

When `i=0` and `j=1`, `myArray[0]=0` and `getArray=3` which are not equal, so the condition in

```
myArray[i] != getArray[j]
```

evaluates to be true and function returns `i` i.e. `0`.